# Multicolumn not utilising all available space in xltabular

Tags: multicolumn, xltabular

I have a table with multiple columns. When using `\multicolumn` once everything works as expected.

However, when using `\multicolumn` twices, with different column `col` values the text does not occupy all the available width.

See the code below:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\title{xltabular}
\author{stephan.hug }
\date{January 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|l|l|l|l|c|l|}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\hline

% Comment/uncomment the line below to observer strange behaviour regarding the filling of all the available horizontal space
\multicolumn{3}{|X|}{foo bar} & Lead &  & \\

\hline

1 & \multicolumn{4}{|X|}{\textbf{a asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf )}
} & 6 \\

\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

I also attached a screenshot showing the behaviour:

In the first screenshot multicolumn works as intended and occupies all available width.
[image: Multicolumn using all available width as intended]

In this screeshot you can see that I uncommented the previous multicolumn line and now the second multicolumn command doesnt occupy all available space.
[image: Multicolumn NOT using all available width]

Comment: `X` is like `p{...}` for some length to be determined, so your X is as wide as a single column. Use `l` if it fits on one line or if you make colums 4 and 5 fixed width you can add the right amount to hsize, or just do it by eye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`longtblr` from `tabularray` could be a solution here. You need to add `hspan=minimum` in column specification in order for `X` to work

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[nopar]{kantlipsum}

\title{xltabular}
\author{stephan.hug }
\date{January 2023}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}

\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {The caption},
  ]{
    colspec = {*2{Q[l]} X Q[l] Q[c] Q[l]},
    hspan = minimal,
    vlines, hlines,
  }
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
  \SetCell[c=3]{}foo bar & & & Lead & & \\
  1 & \SetCell[c=4]{halign=j,font=\bfseries} \kant[1][1] & & & & 6 \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In case you prefer to use left alignment, consider adding `\RaggedRight` (from `ragged2e` package) in the line

```
1 & \SetCell[c=4]{font=\bfseries} \RaggedRight\kant[1][1] & & & & 6 \\
```

This will improve typesetting.